# I get an error that i have already fixed, when trying to open register form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

in the RegistersUsers trait, i used to pass permisions to register view through function showRegistrationForm, but i have restructured my project and i decided that i dont need to pass permissions through that function anymore, so i deleted permissions codes from that trait and i also deleted the model and everything about permission. but the funny thing is when i start my project, i get an error that "Class 'App\Permission' not found"; but in my project there is nothing like permission anymore. let me attach picture to explain more.

[here is the RegistersUsers trait in my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvLTa.png)

[And here is the error i get in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83iSC.png)
[And in my browser, the RegistersUsers looks like this, which is not the same as my file looks. it looks exactly like how it did before i made changes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djhu3.png)

help please, i need this now.

Comment: you should add your code snippet instead of posting images showing code, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Laravel test server or a configured apache? Generally you should never direcly edit framework files.

Anyway seems you're editing different projects, in visual studio code your path is "datastroco-laravel" in your browser "datastroco-mr-umeme"